# How to make IntelliJ color preview recognize a custom Color class?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ there's a feature where you can preview colors in the gutter for regular rgb colors using the `Color` class. However, there are some cases where I prefer the HSL color model, which Java doesn't have, so I made my own class that extends `Color`. Colors instantiated through the custom class don't have previews; is there any way I can tell IntelliJ how to extract a preview from my class?

[image: Example of what I'm talking about]

Here's a short preview of the `HSLColor` class:

```java
public class HSLColor extends Color
{
    private float[] hsl;
    private float alpha;
    
    public HSLColor(float h, float s, float l, float a)
    {
        this(toRGB(h, s, l, a));
        hsl = new float[]{h, s, l};
        alpha = a;
    }
    
    private HSLColor(float[] rgba)
    {
        super(rgba[0], rgba[1], rgba[2], rgba[3]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible without modifying IDE source code or creating a custom plug-in.

Either [submit a feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA), or [write your own plug-in for that](https://jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/intro/welcome.html).